# How to align two inline-blocks of the same height but with different font sizes?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Is there a general method that doesn't involve micro-adjustment to align two inline blocks of the same height but containing words with different font size?

`Vertical-align: middle` does not work. Fine adjustment using `%` on `vertical-align` may not be cross-browser compatible. See [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J5UKj/) page.

Any better solutions?

Comment: `vertical-align: top`? `vertical-align: middle` works if you set it on both elements.

Comment: Use to this vertical-align:top as like   this demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/J5UKj/1/

Comment: Wow, that's fast sir. I was wondering why it seems to work on my demo page but not on my form page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its working if you add `vertical-align:middle` to both element.

You can either apply `vertival-align:top;` to both.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5UKj/2/)